# Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters - Trying to INSERT new data & updating current user data

Tags: php, mysql, database

I was following a tutorial on updating and insert information into databases.

I want to be able to insert additional information into the current user like company and website while also allowing them to update current user information such as first name and last name thats on file. Can this be possible? Any help would be appreciated.

```
    <?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}

// Include config file
require_once "config.php";

// Define variables and initialize with empty values

$company = $website = "";
$company_err = $website_err = "";
$firstname = $lastname = "";
$firstname_err = $lastname_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

            // Validate email/username
    if(empty(trim($_POST["company"]) && ($_POST["website"]))){
        $company_err = "Please enter your company.";
        $website_err = "Please enter a website.";
    } else{
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $param_company, $param_website);

            // Set parameters
            $param_company = trim($_POST["company"]);
            $param_website = trim($_POST["website"]);

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                /* store result */
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                    $company = trim($_POST["company"]);
                    $website = trim($_POST["website"]);

            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }



        // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if(empty($company_err) && empty($website_err)){

        // Prepare an insert statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (company, website) VALUES (?, ?)";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_company, $param_website);

            // Set parameters
            $param_company = $company;
            $param_website = $website;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Redirect to login page
                header("location: welcome.php");
            } else{
               echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

        // Check input errors before updating the database
    if(empty($firstname_err) && empty($lastname_err)){
        // Prepare an update statement
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET firstname, lastname = ? WHERE id = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sse", $param_firstname, $param_lastname, $param_id);

            // Set parameters
            $param_firstname = trim($_POST["firstname"]);
            $param_lastname = trim($_POST["lastname"]);
            $param_id = $_SESSION["id"];

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Updated successfully. Redirect to welcome page
                header("location: welcome.php");
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }


    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

Comment: There is no "e" for `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()`.

Comment: Can I get more information regarding this "e"? New to setting this all up in PHP

Comment: you have too many parameters provided for your query for the 1st and 3rd query . The first one needs just 1 (the email) and the 3rd on needs 2 (lastname, id)

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET firstname, lastname = ? WHERE id = ?";
```

Should be...

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET firstname = ?, lastname = ? WHERE id = ?";
```